# Get mean of multiple selected columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, mean

I want to calculate the mean of all the values in selected columns in a dataframe. For example, I have a dataframe with columns A, B, C, D and E and I want the mean of all the values in columns A, C and E.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame( ( {'A': [1,2,3,4,5],
                      'B': [10,20,30,40,50],
                      'C': [11,21,31,41,51],
                      'D': [12,22,32,42,52],
                      'E': [13,23,33,43,53]} ) )

print( df1 )

print( "Mean of df1:", df1.mean() )

df2 = pd.concat( [df1['A'], df1['C'], df1['E'] ], ignore_index=True )
print( df2 )
print( "Mean of df2:", df2.mean() )

df3 = pd.DataFrame()
df3 = pd.concat( [ df3, df1['A'] ], ignore_index=True )
df3 = pd.concat( [ df3, df1['C'] ], ignore_index=True )
df3 = pd.concat( [ df3, df1['E'] ], ignore_index=True )
print( df3 )
print( "Mean of df3:", df3.mean() )
```

df2 gets me the right answer, but I need to create a new dataframe to get it.

I though something like `df1['A', 'C', 'E'].mean()` would work but it returns the mean values for each column, not the combined average.  Is there a way to do this without creating a new dataframe?  I also need other data statistics like .std(), .min(), max() so this isn't just a one-off calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options that I know of:

for mean(), min(), max()  you can use mean of mean, min of min, max of max this would yield, mean, min, max of all the elements of A, C, E.

So you can use:
for mean():`enter code here`

```
df1[['A','C','E']].apply(np.mean).mean()
df1[['A','C','E']].values.mean()
```

Any one of the above should give you the mean of all the elements of columns A, C, E.

for min():

```
df1[['A','C','E']].apply(np.min).min()
df1[['A','C','E']].values.min()
```

For max():

```
df1[['A','C','E']].apply(np.max).max()
df1[['A','C','E']].values.max()
```

For std()

```
df1[['A','C','E']].apply(np.std).std()    ##  this will not give error, but gives a 
                       value that is not what you want.
df1[['A','C','E']].values.std()    # this gives the std of all the elements of columns A, C, E.
```

std of std will not give the std of all the elements.

Comment: when I use `std= df1[['A','C','E']].values.std()` I get a value of 17.93, whereas the correct value should be 18.56.

Comment: Columns A, C, E  has elements   [1, 11, 13, 2, 21, 23, 3, 31, 33, 4, 41, 43, 5, 51, 53].  This is how you get the elements of  A, C, E :        df1[['A','C','E']].stack().values   ;                              np.std([1, 11, 13, 2, 21, 23, 3, 31, 33, 4, 41, 43, 5, 51, 53])    gives      17.93197020841702;       How did you get 18.56?

Comment: `df2 = pd.concat( [df1['A'], df1['C'], df1['E'] ], ignore_index=True )` yields `df2.std()=18.5613` whereas `df1[['A','C','E']].values.std()=17.9319`

Comment: standard deviation for a population is calculated using n, where as std for a sample is caluculated using (n-1).  
       When you applied df2.std(), it took the default value as n-1,  This is set using the parameter ddof = 1.  If you set this parameter to 0, that is ddof = 0
you get the value of 17.93    

       df2.std(ddof = 0)  ## gives 17.93 ; here n (15) is taken for the calculation   
       df2.std(ddof = 1)  ## gives 18.5613 ; here n -1 (14) is taken for the calculation   

       Please take a look about population standard deviation vs sample standard deviation.

Answer (score 3):

Caveat: only okay if the columns are of the same length. If not it would give the wrong answer (as the comments pointed out).

```
mean = df1[['A', 'C', 'E']].mean(axis=1).mean()    
print(mean)
```

Comment: @jezrael Not in this case because the columns have the same number of elements each. Thus `df1[['A', 'B', 'C']].mean().mean() == df1[['A', 'C', 'E']].stack().mean()`.

Comment: Indeed, @jezrael would be right it would be different if they are of different lengths. so I'd caveat that it would only work if the columns have the same length.

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape `DataFrame` to `Series with Multiindex` by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and then use `mean`:

```
df2 = df1[['A', 'C', 'E']].stack()
print (df2)
0  A     1
   C    11
   E    13
1  A     2
   C    21
   E    23
2  A     3
   C    31
   E    33
3  A     4
   C    41
   E    43
4  A     5
   C    51
   E    53
dtype: int64

print( "Mean of df2:", df2.mean() )
Mean of df2: 22.333333333333332
```

Another idea is convert values to numpy 2d array and then use [`np.mean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html?highlight=mean#numpy.mean):

```
df21 = df1[['A', 'C', 'E']]
print( df21 )
   A   C   E
0  1  11  13
1  2  21  23
2  3  31  33
3  4  41  43
4  5  51  53

print(df21.to_numpy())
[[ 1 11 13]
 [ 2 21 23]
 [ 3 31 33]
 [ 4 41 43]
 [ 5 51 53]]

print( "Mean of df2:", np.mean(df21.to_numpy()) )
Mean of df2: 22.333333333333332
```